# Python web server to query MySQL DB and test multiple Tensorflow models

Tags: python, tensorflow, web, backend, tensorflow-lite

I want to build a web-based application that a few people would use to process images and test Tensorflow / Tensorflow Lite models. The backend will be implemented in Python and needs to be able to:

- Query a MySQL database containing images
- Load one or more Tensorflow /TFLite models on request
- Perform inference using the retrieved images and the loaded models

On the frontend side, I have some Javascript code to show and process the images and I want to integrate this code in the application. I also need some basic authentication. I don't have particular requirements about performances because only one or two people will be using the application simultaneously.

I was thinking about FastAPI because it's simple but I'm not sure it can satisfy my requirements without extra work. Are there some obvious disadvantages, or is there a more suitable framework for this type of project?